# Scrapy: Extract links

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy, trying to extract subtitles from `www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/episode_scripts.php?tv-show=bojack-horseman-2014`

This is my `scrape.py` code which is Spider file

```
 from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
 from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
 from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
 from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
 from scrapy.item import Item, Field
 import re

ss_base_url = "https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/episode_scripts.php"

class Script(Item):
    url = Field()
    episode_name = Field()
    script = Field()

class SubtitleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "scrape"
    allowed_domains = ['www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk']
    start_urls = [ss_base_url]
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/episode_scripts.php?tv-show=bojack-horseman-2014&episode=\w+']),
             callback="parse_script",
             follow=True),)

    def fix_field_names(self, field_name):
        field_name = re.sub(" ","_", field_name)
        field_name = re.sub(":","", field_name)
        return field_name

    def parse_script(self, response):
        x = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        script = Script()
        script['url'] = response.url
        script['episode_name'] = "".join(x.select("//h3/text()").extract())
        script['script'] = "\n".join(x.select("//div[@class='episode_script']/text()").extract())
        return script
```

I am trying to extract all seasons subtitles from `https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/episode_scripts.php?tv-show=bojack-horseman-2014`

Subtitles are present inside these links

```
https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=bojack-horseman-2014&episode=s01e01

https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?tv-show=bojack-horseman-2014&episode=s01e02
```

when I run

```
 scrapy crawl --nolog scrape
```

I should get those above links as output.
But its not returning nothing , where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regular expression for matching the links contains a question mark wich needs to be escaped for your match to work, it should work if you change it to this:

```
'\/view_episode_scripts\.php\?tv-show=bojack-horseman-2014&episode=\w+'
```

When you run the script with --nolog it would not log the links, so you would need to remove that as well.